# Getting error messages when mining tweets

Tags: r, twitter, tm

I am using R to mine tweets. However, I get two messages that completely confuse me. Therefore, I do not know how to fix the errors. Could I call on your supeR poweRs for help?

```
> wordcloud(Ossoff_clean, random.order = F, max.words = 40, scale = c(3,0.5), colors = rainbow(50))
Error in tolower(txt) : invalid input 'Karen Handel Projected to Win GeorgiaElection Laughing My Ossoff httpstcoopPoYKQNU ������������������ MAGA TCOT TLOT CCOT TeaParty' in 'utf8towcs'
```

I don't know how to get rid of the questions marks in the black geo shape.

```
> str(Ossoff_text)
Error in strtrim(encodeString(object, quote = "\"", na.encode = FALSE),  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<a0><bd>\x<65>d<b1>\u008d\xed<a0><bd>\xed<b1>\u008d\xed<a0><bd>\xed<b1>\u008d #MAGA #TCOT #TLOT #CCOT #TeaParty"'
```

I have no clue why I am getting this error message.